# HTML in MVC RouteLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a RouteLink constructed like so

```
<p class="articleLink">
    @MvcHelper.Html.RouteLink(article.Title, "Article_Route", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "articleId", article.Id }, { "seoUrl", article.SeoUrl } }))
</p>
```

However, `article.Title` could potentially contain HTML i.e. the value could be `<em>Sample</em> Title` which in turn gets rendered like so

```
<a href="/Article/111111/Sample-Title">&lt;em&gt;Sample&lt;/em&gt; Title</a>
```

Is there any way to prevent the HTML from being escaped, and instead to be treated as actual HTML? Or do I need to create a standard HTML `<a href...` link in this case (thus losing all the niceties associated with the RouteLink helper).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want HTML inside your anchor don't use the `Html.RouteLink` (because it will HTML encode the link text by default as you noticed) instead of build your `a` tag by hand with using `Url.RouteUrl` to generate the url:

```
<p class="articleLink">
    <a href="@(Url.RouteUrl("Article_Route",
                   new RouteValueDictionary() 
                      { { "articleId", article.Id }, 
                        { "seoUrl", article.SeoUrl } }))">
        @Html.Raw(article.Title)
    </a>
</p>
```

Or you can create your own non encoding `RouteLink` helper.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [HtmlHelper.Raw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). Having said that, it is probably not a good idea to keep any HTML in your model/view model, which is against the principle of separation of model and presentation, also a security hazard.

Comment: That is a totally different Helper method.