# HTML in Ajax.RouteLink linkText

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I emit HTML (something other than plain text) for the `linkText` to `Ajax.RouteLink`?

Instead of this:

```
@Ajax.RouteLink("X",  ...)
```

I want:

```
@Ajax.RouteLink("<i class='icon-check'></i>", ...)
```

But, this emits the HTML encoded.

Comment: the @symbol implies you're using MVC Razor. True?

Comment: Yes. This is an MVC-4 Razor app.

Comment: Something along the same lines - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108674/html-in-mvc-routelink

Comment: thats a great alternative. @tig, is are you attached to that particular helper, or just want those results?

Comment: Actually, what I'd really like is to know what the helper is really doing; i don't mind creating my own.